# Mongo 2.6.4 won't stepDown() because can't find a secondary within 10 seconds, but rs.status() shows optimeDates in sync

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I'm attempting to step down my mongo primary and have my secondaries take over - mongo won't step down and says the my secondaries are more than 10 seconds out of sync.  Yet my replica set says they are in sync - I'm baffled and it is likely something silly I'm missing

here's my output:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
sessionV2:PRIMARY> rs.stepDown()
{
    "closest" : NumberLong(0),
    "difference" : NumberLong(1441842526),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "no secondaries within 10 seconds of my optime"
}
sessionV2:PRIMARY> rs.status()   
{
    "set" : "sessionV2",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-09-09T23:48:53Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
        "_id" : 0,
        "name" : "sessionv2-mongo-replset-moprd1-02:27017",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 1,
        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
        "uptime" : 2659,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1441842533, 61),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-09-09T23:48:53Z"),
        "electionTime" : Timestamp(1441839881, 1),
        "electionDate" : ISODate("2015-09-09T23:04:41Z"),
        "self" : true
    },
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "sessionv2-mongo-replset-moprd1-01:27017",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 2,
        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
        "uptime" : 2658,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1441842531, 120),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-09-09T23:48:51Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-09-09T23:48:51Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-09-09T23:48:51Z"),
        "pingMs" : 0,
        "syncingTo" : "sessionv2-mongo-replset-moprd1-03:27017"
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "name" : "sessionv2-mongo-replset-moprd1-03:27017",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 2,
        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
        "uptime" : 2658,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1441842531, 120),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-09-09T23:48:51Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-09-09T23:48:51Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2015-09-09T23:48:52Z"),
        "pingMs" : 0,
        "syncingTo" : "sessionv2-mongo-replset-moprd1-02:27017"
    }
],
"ok" : 1
}
sessionV2:PRIMARY>
```

here's what the primary reports as far a status:

```
sessionV2:PRIMARY>  rs.printSlaveReplicationInfo()
    source: sessionv2-mongo-replset-moprd1-01:27017
    syncedTo: Wed Sep 09 2015 19:15:02 GMT-0500 (CDT)
    1 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary 
    source: sessionv2-mongo-replset-moprd1-03:27017
    syncedTo: Wed Sep 09 2015 19:15:02 GMT-0500 (CDT)
    1 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary 
    sessionV2:PRIMARY>
```

and an oplog view from a secondary:

```
sessionV2:SECONDARY> db.getReplicationInfo()
{
"logSizeMB" : 5120,
"usedMB" : 5077.25,
"timeDiff" : 12226,
"timeDiffHours" : 3.4,
"tFirst" : "Wed Sep 09 2015 15:53:29 GMT-0500 (CDT)",
"tLast" : "Wed Sep 09 2015 19:17:15 GMT-0500 (CDT)",
"now" : "Wed Sep 09 2015 19:17:15 GMT-0500 (CDT)"
}
```

thanks in advance!

2015 Sept 10th update:
we stopped each secondary and performed an initial sync from primary - then attempted to step down the primary again - it looks like the PRIMARY can't find the secondary oplogDate (we were unsure if forcing would free a SECONDARY to take PRIMARY)

```
sessionV2:PRIMARY> db.runCommand( { replSetStepDown: 60, force: false } ) 
{
"closest" : NumberLong(0),
"difference" : NumberLong(1441936029),
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "no secondaries within 10 seconds of my optime"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

issue solved! - I was playing with workarounds and documenting the replica setup - our initial scripts set the primary at default priority and the secondaries at priority 0 (which means they will never take PRIMARY role) - so basically -> bad config and the error message doesn't give any info onto the root problem (the docs are pretty clear, just missed it because I trusted our init scripts) - if you run into this and your replicaset oplogs are up to date, double check that the priorities are not set at 0